# JQuery custom objects

Tags: jquery, object

I'm new to JQuery. As an exercise I have to translate javascript code as much as possible into JQuery.

Javascript:

```
function Blog(body, date,image){
      this.body = body;
      this.date = date;
      this.image = image;
}

Blog.prototype.toHTML = function(highlight) {}
```

My JQuery equivalent:

```
$.Blog=function(body, date, image){
    this.body=body;
    this.date=date;
    this.image=image;
}

$.Blog.fn.toHTML=function(highlight){}
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Where did you get this exercise from?  I think you could easily make the argument that this function constructor/object is better off the way it is.  If your paying for this course ask for your money back.

Comment: I have a hard time getting the point of doing that. You don't "translate" Javascript into jquery, jquery IS Javascript. Here you're simply attaching functions to the jquery object. I wonder who gave you that kind of exercise.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. There is no difference. You can't "turn JavaScript into jQuery", that statement does not make any sense.